# Proof that in a graph of $2$ or more vertrex, there's at least $2$ of them that have the same degree

Tags: graph-theory, proof-writing

That's what I what to prove let $G$ be an undirected graph such it has $2$ or more vertex, there's at least $2$ vertex that have the same degree.

I'm almost certain that, supposing that it's possible to have a undirected graph such every of it's vertex degree is different, and trying to construct this graph, I'll get a contradiction. But I don't know how to formalize this.

Any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint 1:** If there are $n$ vertices, what is the largest possible degree? What are the possible degrees, if they are all different?

**Hint 2:** It is possible to have a vertex of maximal degree, and another one of degree 0?

Comment: Let's see, The maximum degree a vertex can have is $n-1$. If there are all different, then it forcefully has to be $n-1,n-2,n-3,...,0$.

But it's impossible to have a vertex connected to all the other vertex, and a vertex with no edges at the same time, and there's the contradiction. Thanks.

Comment: @FranckN Perfect, yw :)